# Adding PDF Printer in JPOS.xml

Tags: java, oracle, javapos, jpos

I'm new in JAVA, and especially in ORPOS application. I need to add a PDF Printer to ORPOS application to simulate the real printer. 
 
I find that in `JPOS.xml` I must change the printer details but I don't know what details to change. I installed the `PDF24` printer **but how to add in `JPOS.xml`** ?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle doesn't test network printing to the PDF24 driver so no guarantee that the following will work nor is this configuration supported.

You will need to install the ORPOS client for a Network printer as JPOS won't work without JPOS drivers for PDF24. Let's assume a Windows client with the PDF24 driver installed and ORPOS 14.0.

For 14.0 there will be a prompt during the install for Network Printer Support, choose Page Printer and NEXT.  Enter the printer name PDF24 PDF (or whatever name it has).  The Print Language should be PostScript.  Enter next and complete the install.  Don't select the option for a JPOS printer!  For other releases there may be only an option for a Network printer without the option for page or roll, so check network printer and enter the name and language.

If you're intent is to just be able to test without a printer then leave the JPOS printer simulated and the printer output will be sent to the Java console.